# Select substring based on first match, requiring an earlier 2nd pattern match too

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pull a specific Session ID from some very messy log files and even looking at other examples am having a hard time implementing any regular expressions that appear to work. The logs come in reading like this, and I am trying to collect the specific SessionId that appears after a given an earlier string is found for the first time "TestAPIurl"

```
b'{\n  "log": {\n    "version": "1.2",\n    "creator": {\n      "name": "mitmproxy har_dump",
\n      "version": "0.1",\n      "GET": "TestAPIurl"\n    },
\n    "entries": [\n      {\n        "startedDateTime": "2021-10-11T22:39:30.916773+00:00",
\n        "sessionId": "1521-35236erg-fggr4",\n        "request": {\n          "method": "POST",\n
```

I'm struggling with the regex required to ensure that I only get the sessionId that comes after the proper TestAPIurl. I have managed to be able to capture the sessionID value but there are multiple sessionIds and I am having difficulty making sure I get the first one after the pattern "TestAPIurl" as the space and values between "TestAPIurl" and the next "sessionId" can vary a lot.

```
m = re.search('(?<=sessionId":\s.).*(?=")', file)
m.group()
```

Comment: This looks like JSON. Can it be parsed/decoded as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that looks a lot like JSON. Is processing it as JSON an option? If so, I'd definitely try to make that work as I'd have complete control over knowing which session belongs to which request.

But if it's not...

I stripped your sample data down, then doubled it up, making **TestAPIurlFoo** and **TestAPIurlBar**:

```py
import re

input = '''
{\n  "log": {\n
\n     "version": "0.1",\n  "GET": "TestAPIurlFoo" },
\n   "entries": [\n  {\n
\n     "sessionId": "sessionIdFoo",\n  "request": {\n "method": "POST",\n ...
{\n  "log": {\n
\n      "version": "0.1",\n  "GET": "TestAPIurlBar" },
\n    "entries": [\n  {\n
\n      "sessionId": "sessionIdBar",\n  "request": {\n "method": "POST",\n ...
'''

api_url_names = ['TestAPIurlFoo','TestAPIurlBar', 'TestAPIurlBaz']

for api_url_name in api_url_names:
    pattern = f'"{api_url_name}".+?"sessionId": "(.+?)"'  # build pattern for either Foo or Bar

    match = re.search(pattern, input, re.DOTALL)  # DOTALL so that `.` matches newlines
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

and I get the following:

```
sessionIdFoo
sessionIdBar
```

The search for **TestAPIurlBaz** returns nothing, which I think is what you want.  re.DOTALL allows search to match text across line breaks with `.` (dot) character class[^1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

I think of your requirement, in regex terms, like:

> the pattern I want starts with *this* API-url and ends with the first session id

Here's the pattern for Foo:

```
"TestAPIurlFoo".+?"sessionId": "(.+?)"
```

`.+?` means, *the least amount of characters between the literals `"TestAPIurlFoo"` and `"sessionId"`*.

Comment: The logs seemed so messy I assumed only parts were in JSON but fought with it more and got it to at least give a parent json, but the final string needing parsing is not. So in both cases this has helped and I have it working now. Thank you

Comment: @DickMcManus, alright. Also, I did figure out the significance of the newlines, and added the `re.DOTALL` flag, which seems more regex-y. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that will return the value of the `sessionId` key.

```py
>>> re.search('"sessionId"\s*:\s*"(.+?)"', file).group(1)
1521-35236erg-fggr4
```

Note that the string you provided was prefixed with `b`, so it looks like a `bytes` rather than a `str` - you may have to prefix the regular expression pattern with `b` as well, or pass something like `file.decode("utf8")` instead of just `file` to `re.search()`.

Comment: This will return the first match of `"sessionId"`, but irrespective of the "association" with 'TestAPIurl'. If there were two session Ids, and OP wanted the second, this solution would only return the first.

Comment: ch,  didn't even notice. oh well...